# How do I fix this error - Deprecated function?

Tags: php, drupal

My hosting provider recently upgraded our php version and now I am getting this error:

```
Deprecated function: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in drupal_load() (line 1105 of /mysite/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

My drupal is up to date. I have not modified bootstrap.inc.

Here's the drupal_load function:

```
function drupal_load($type, $name) {
  // Once a file is included this can't be reversed during a request so do not
  // use drupal_static() here.
  static $files = array();

  if (isset($files[$type][$name])) {
    return TRUE;
  }

  $filename = drupal_get_filename($type, $name);

  if ($filename) {
    include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $filename;
    $files[$type][$name] = TRUE;

    return TRUE;
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: are all your modules up to date? This could be due to a module being loaded in that has the deprecated assignment of the return value by reference in it.

Comment: Yes I just updated everything

Comment: did you ever solve this issue>?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem in a following way:

Open the project in netbeans, go to projects(on the left), right click on the project->find

and type in &new

netbeans will go trough all the files and find keyword, than just remove & before new and it will solve the deprecated problem.

other way you can go is use

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
error_reporting(0);
```

it will disable error reporting. I DO NOT RECOMMEND IT.